# Write text to the Visual Studio 2010 output window in C++-CLI

Tags: .net, winforms, debugging, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a Windows Forms application that I need to write to the output window from. `OutputDebugString("text");` doesn't work - no output. I tried some others as well, but I didn't get any to work. Is there a function that I can just call like the following?

```
DebugWriteLine("text");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `OutputDebugString("text");` doesn't work, then try the following (many thanks to [Lol4t0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774651/lol4t0) for this):

1. Go into the project settings of your EXE to debug.
2. Select the Debugging property page.
3. Select 'Mixed' for the Debugger type.

Comment: This also allow you to debug the both types of code (Managed and Unmanaged code) in VS.

Answer (score 1):

`OutputDebugString` should work fine.  The problem (and the comments confirm this) is likely that you're using managed-only debugging.  If you enable mixed-mode (or native-only) debugging, you'll get the native debug output.

If you want output sent to a managed debugger, check out the [`Debug`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx) and [`Trace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) classes in the `System::Diagnostics` namespace.

Then there's [`System::Diagnostics::Debugger::Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.log.aspx), which jumps through some hoops to be compatible with both native and managed debuggers (and has weird behavior as a result of the differences).  I believe that when a native debugger is attached, this actually calls `OutputDebugString`, and uses `System::Diagnostics::Debug` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Visual Studio.

`OutputDebugString("text");`

Here's the documentation for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx

If it's not working for you I recommend reading through the comments at the MSDN page, maybe your problem is similar to one of the ones listed there, for example:

> In Visual Studio 2008, the output of this function goes to the "Immediate Window", not the Output window. The immediate window is closed by default, so it seems like the output is lost.
>
> Also, if you find "Winbase.h (include Windows.h)" confusing, the correct include directive for a c++ native application is
>
> ```
> #include <windows.h>
> ```

I realize you're using 2010, not 2008, but it may still apply.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't. do you know any possible situations in which it does not work?

Comment: If you have anything else running that can intercept debug output, like DebugView, you may not see it in Visual Studio.
I've added more info to the original answer.

Comment: May be the problem is that author debug `c++-cli` application using only managed debugger, so native debugger is not connected and ouput goes straight to null. There is a link, shows how to enable native debugging: http://omnitechie.com/blogengine/post/2009/09/C2b2bCLI-debugging.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General and check the "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" Checkbox.